# HTML & CSS: How to put a line between some rows of tables but not all

Tags: html, css

I want to have lines between some of the rows in my table, but not all of them. I have tried many ways of doing it but something weird always happens. What I have so far is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr id="border-top" align="center"><th>A</th><td>B</td></tr>
      <tr id="border-top" align="center"><th>1</th><td>11</td></tr>
      <tr align="center"><th>2</th><td>12</td></tr>
      <tr id="border-top" align="center"><th>3</th><td>13</td></tr>
      <tr id="border-top" align="center"><th>4</th><td>14</td></tr>
      <tr align="center"><th>5</th><td>15</td></tr>
      <tr id="border-top" align="center"><th>6</th><td>16</td></tr>
      <tr id="border-top" align="center"><th>7</th><td>17</td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this CSS:

```
#border-top{
    text-align:center;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    display:block;
}
```

But my output looks like this with the line `display:block;`

[image: this]

Or like this without it:

[image: this]

I want the lines to be there like in the first picture. But I want them to all be properly aligned like in the second picture. How should I be going about doing this instead?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you like an empty row between some rows?

Comment: FYI, `id` attributes should be unique in your page.  In other words, you should have only one `id` (with the same value) per page.  Use `class` instead for this particular use case (i.e. multiple elements to share the same CSS `class`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `id` attributes should be unique in your page. In other words, you should have only one `id` (with the same value) per page. Use `class` instead for this particular use case (i.e. multiple elements to share the same CSS `class`)

Second, the `tr` themselves will not get decorated with your CSS. Try decorating the `th`s and the `td`s.

You can can do so by adding this to your CSS rule:

```
.border-top td, .border-top th{...}
```

**See example below**:

```css
.border-top td, .border-top th {
  border-top: 1px solid green;
}

table { 
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr class="border-top" align="center">
    <th>A</th>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="border-top" align="center">
    <th>1</th>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <th>2</th>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="border-top" align="center">
    <th>3</th>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="border-top" align="center">
    <th>4</th>
    <td>14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <th>5</th>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="border-top" align="center">
    <th>6</th>
    <td>16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="border-top" align="center">
    <th>7</th>
    <td>17</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This looks great, but it leaves a slight gap between the line above each column. Is there a way to do this without the line?

Comment: @Tyler I am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td{
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;  
}
```

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>12</td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>12</td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>12</th>
      </tr>      
    </table>
```